# Java source code: remove method implementation code and keep signatures?

Tags: java, ide

Are there any tools to remove method implementation code and keep signatures?

For example I would like this class,

```
    class Foo {

    public void doSomething(int value, String name) {
       // code do something 
    }


    public int getSomething(int value, String name) {
           // code here
    }

    public Bar getBar(int value, String name) {
           // code here
    }
}
```

To become:

```
class Foo {

    public void doSomething(int value, String name) {

    }


    public int getSomething(int value, String name) {
       return 0;
    }

    public Bar getBar(int value, String name) {
       return null;
    }
}
```

The purpose is to provide skeleton source code (not open source) for IDE code-complete.

Comment: Looks like you may want to read up on `interface`.

Comment: well. code contains both interface and classes.

Comment: Then I'm struggling to see your problem. Why would you need empty implementations when you have interfaces?

Comment: What I meant: some are interfaces, some are classes. Mostly classes.

Comment: Why not make `Foo` implement `FooInterface` and provide `FooInterface` for code completion? (sorry - that's not exactly what you're asking, but I'm really curious)

Comment: Understand. But this is existing code, not new code. There are 1000s classes

Comment: attaching javadoc did not help for code-completion.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Intellij IDE 2019 latest version. Also using Eclipse Mar 2 which does not support gradle very well. So I am trying to move to Intellij.

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a solution for this?